# Segmentation Fault when using getline() C

Tags: c, getline

Every other thread I looked at had the problem of not initializing line as NULL and len as 0. This is part of my code:

```
    char* line = NULL;
    char* line2 = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t len2 = 0;
    char *function = NULL;
    size_t read, read2;       //read2 gia to config
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, op)) != -1)
    {
            line[read - 2] = 0;
            char* pch;
            pch = strtok(line, " ");
            strcpy(function, pch);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if `read < 2`?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that the variables are not initialized as you coded it in their definitions? Do you mean that `line` is `NULL` and `len` is `0` *after* the call to `getline`? Can you please elaborate? And if possible also please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Why are you so sure, that the getline() is the cause of the segfault? You are certainly not using a debugger, otherwise you would probably already have found your mistake, so how can you tell that it isn't the `strcpy()` afterwards, which tries to copy something to the `NULL` pointer stored in `*function`? Did you by chance mean `function = strdup(pch);`?

Comment: Since you've not shown the code that uses `line2`, `len2`, `read2`, nor the rest of the loop, we can't tell whether there's a problem in the unshown code.  An MCVE ([MCVE]) would not include those variables.  (Personally, if I had two sets of variables, they'd be `line1` and `line2`, not `line` and `line2`, but lots of people do it your way — and it annoys me when I see it.). However, you've not allocated space for `function` to point at, so `strcpy(function, pch)` fails — probably with a segmentation fault.

Comment: this is wrong: `strcpy(function, pch);` because `function` is not pointing to memory that your program owns. (it is pointing to `NULL`, which is effectively to address 0;

Comment: what is this line: `line[read - 2] = 0;` expecting to accomplish?  If it is trying to eliminate the trailing newline, a viable method would be: `char *newline = strchr( line, '\n' );  if( newline ) *newline = '\0';`

Comment: BTW: the posted code has exactly the same problem as the threads you looked at.  I.E. before every call to `getline()`, need to initialize `line` to NULL and `len` to 0

Comment: `op` is not defined/set within the posted code. so exactly what does it contain?

Comment: When calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `strcpy(function, pch);` would be better written as: `function = strdup(pch);`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple issues,

1. If `read < 2` then your index is smaller than `0`
2. If `pch` is `NULL`, then you dereference a `NULL` pointer

   Notes about `strtok()`,

   - It returns `NULL` when it doesn't find the separator.
   - It's really bad for treating multiple strings or using it in multithreaded programs because it's not reentrant.
   - There is always a better alternative involving `strchr()`, `strstr()` or `strpbrk()`, all of which don't have the limitations of `strtok()`.

   Note, I DO NOT mean that you should not use `strtok()`, there are legitimate situations where it's the BEST option, I am just warning you about some of it's limitations and clarifying it's intended behavior so that you use it correctly, assuming that it returned something just because you "*know*" the input, is simply a bad programming practice. ALWAYS check for errors, it's better to know why the program failed than to be completely puzzled.

   In fact, saying or thinking that "*you know the input*" is wrong, because

   1. What's the point of writing code to treat a single input?
   2. It's not what you think, some characters might be quite clear to you but editors can render a `'\t'` tab character just like they do with a `' '` white space.

You should not blame it on `getline()` because it's known to work correctly so it's hardly it's fault.

Your program invokes *undefined behavior*, so where exactly the problem happens is not possible to tell, because it might occur somewhere and the program continues until someone does something that triggers the segmentation fault.

Comment: I have no doubt that there are multiple problems in the rest of the program, thanks for the tips. But it does reach Segmentation fault before moving on to the rest of the lines, so I'm confused as to why.

Comment: Undefined behavior, means that you can't know where the SIGSEGV will occur.

Comment: @meerto Just use a debugger and step through the code line by line, you will suddenly say "*oh! this is the problem, ohhhh I am so ....*", ;)

Comment: Hahah! I did gdb but I'm fairly new at using it. It complained: "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_getdelim (lineptr=0x7fffffffdcc0, n=0x7fffffffdcc8, delimiter=10, fp=0x0)
    at iogetdelim.c:52
52 iogetdelim.c: No such file or directory."